# Yii2 : Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection refused #111] in a godaddy hosting

Tags: php, email, yii2, smtp, swiftmailer

I'm trying to use Swift Mailer in Yii2.

My host is Godaddy and I'm trying to use a gmail account to send emails.

The code seems to be working fine, but when I try to use it I receive the error:
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection refused #111]

I double-checked that I'm using the correct credentials for gmail. Could it be an issue with my host and if so, is there a way to fix it?
This is the code

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'transport' => [
                    'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                    'host'=>'smtp.gmail.com',
                    'username'=>'myUserName@gmail.com',
                    'password'=>'******',
                    'port'=>'587',
                    'encryption'=>'tls',
                ],
            'useFileTransport' => false, //for the testing purpose, you need to enable this


        ],
I also tried with **`'class' => 'Swift_MailTransport',`**
but the error was not resolved.

The error is
```

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com
>   [Connection refused #111]

Please help me in this regard.
Thanks,

Comment: check for yusername and password

Comment: #sciasEdge it is confirmed that I am entering the correct username and password

Comment: then  could be that godaddy don't allow the use of a gmail.com mail server  .. check if godaddy give  you a proper  mail server  and configure this mail server for the swifmailer transport

Comment: Hmmm. That is  a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your configuration settings for Swift Mailer are unable to connect host Gmail, try below changes, most probably it will work:

```
'mailer' => [
    'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
    'useFileTransport' => false,
    'transport' => [
        'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
        'host'=>'smtp.gmail.com',
        'username'=>'myUserName@gmail.com',
        'password'=>'******',
        'port'=>'465',
        'encryption'=>'ssl',
    ],
],
```

Changes made:

```
'port'=>'465',
'encryption'=>'ssl',
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that something in your config is wrong, try to change your config to:

```
   'port'=>'465',
   'encryption'=>'ssl'
```